# Sitefinity Stylesheet override 5.2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, sitefinity

I need to remove Sitefinity's out of the box styling for all elements on a master page that we create. I've poured over tons of documents but they all leave me wanting more, a cleaner, more simplistic way to achieve this. CSS overrides seem bulky, and removing it from the config file will destroy my business users ability to work within the CMS and update quickly. Also, I have tried the custom widget overrides on the User Control level, and still am not a fan of the results.

So, how does one do this, keep clean code, and make it easy for business users?

Comment: As a start have you turned off the basic theme in the Templates section of the site, you need to do this per template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sean's right - if you don't use the default theme, no styling will be added to your template by Sitefinity.

Given your forum thread on [sitefinity.com](http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/forums/designing-styling/overriding-all-radcontrol-styling-globally-), you're not so much running into trouble because of Sitefinity, but because of using the default RadControls.

If you replace those with a custom solution, not only will there be no styling added, the html markup itself will be much cleaner.

You could for instance use one of the Marketplace navigation controls or use [KendoUI](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/menu/index.html) in combination with a sitemapdatasource, which would give you something like this:

```
<ul id="sitepanelnav" class="sitepanelnav k-group" data-role="treeview" >
...
<li class="k-item">
 <div class="k-mid">
  <span class="k-in">
   <a href="/page2.aspx">linktext</a>
  </span>
 </div>
</li>
...
</ul>
```

But if you're really adament about clean markup and clean styling, you can use the API to render out a 100% clean *ul/li* and take it from there with 100% control.

If you're still set on using the RadControls, start with the [Stylebuilder](http://stylebuilder.telerik.com/) to visually build out the basics of your design, then manually tweak/integrate & optimize the generated .css files.

The name you enter as a skin, is the name you should add as 'designer skin' in the widget options.

In a nutshell: Yes it can be done, but it either takes some coding or some styling effort, which one you prefer is up to you of course.

Comment: Thanks @jbokkers, but I guess I meant ALL styles found inherit in the stylesheet that sitefinity inserts, not just the ones on nav widgets and the like, but literally every single style. Does that make it a bit clearer?

Comment: Hey Nick,
Yes it does and like I said "if you don't use the default theme, no styles will be added by Sitefinity." If you're seeying any styles being added, its either A) because of a RadControl widget on the page or B) you've got Browse and edit turned on which overlays editing capabilites on the live browsing site.

Take a look here https://gist.github.com/4124678 to see view-source on a demo SF v5 homepage. No inline styling whatsoever and just my own .css file being loaded. Feel free to hit me up outside of SO if you'd like to talk further about it...

Jochem